# how to get a multiline alert title on Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Is there a way to get more than the 2 lines for the Alert title in an `AlertDialog`?

I only find "creating a custom dialog" as a possible solution.

Ideally however, one could just set an `attribute` - but I can't find any.

EDIT:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertAndCallUtility.this).create();
alertDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.alert_title));
alertDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.alert_msg));
alertDialog.setButton(getString(R.string.alert_OK),
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
        }});
alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
alertDialog.show();
```

and xml

```
<string name="alert_OK">OK:</string>
<string name="alert_title">Please correct your input, parameters are missing.</string>
<string name="alert_msg">Please enter them in the EXTRA tab.</string>
```

as mentioned, inserting a \n right before "..missing", just cuts it off and one only sees the first two lines until "are" of the title.

Comment: What happens if you insert a `\n` in the title?

Comment: I think you can use "\n" in setting title, not tried but may be working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a long-shot, but have you tried using `\n` in your title for force a newline?

Comment: Could you add an example, and a screenshot?

Comment: If you're using the Android emulator you can just screenshot it with Print Screen (in Windows at least), then crop, save it using Paint.
If you're using a physical phone then I think there are some apps that will let you store a screenshot. Or you could take a photo. :)

Comment: ..taking a screenshot seems to be more complicated than I though - strange! I mean I am not the only one who needs that. Anyway I need to "root" the phone. Don't know what this means... anyway as explained it just cuts off the text. without the \n it adds at least some dots like ...at the end to show that the text continues

Comment: You can take screenshots of emulator by going into DDMS then go to Devices there you will find Capture. Click on Capture button to take a snapshot.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use AlertDialog.Builder().setCustomTitle():

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setText("your very long title here");
dialogBuilder.setCustomTitle(textView);
```